# An abstract nonsense proof of the Hurewicz theorem

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff

The ordinary homotopy groups of a space $X$ are the homotopy groups of the corresponding singular simplicial set $Sing(X)$. The ordinary homology groups of $X$ are the homotopy groups of the simplicial set $F(Sing(X))$, where $F$ is the functor that replaces each set $Sing(X)_n$ with the free abelian group on that set. There should obviously be some nice property of $F$ that makes the Hurewicz theorem work, but all the proofs I can find in the literature do things entirely by hand at the level of checking individual maps and homotopies to $X$. Is this nice property known? Is there a satisfying answer?

Comment: Pick a simplicial group model $G$ for the loop space of $X$, then the Hurewicz homomorphism is realized as that induced on $G\to G/[G,G]$. This is in many places, e. g. May

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე that's a more than slightly ambiguous reference, tbh.

Comment: Hurewicz theorem is really the theorem about the homotopy category of spaces, thus the abstract $(\infty, 1)$-category of spaces is the proper setting for stating and proving it, and indeed it has a simple abstract proof.  Is this what you're asking or are you really interested in the properties of the specific simplicial model? In the latter case you're bound to explicit computations.

Comment: @anton I'd be interested to see the simple abstract proof, so that I can work out whether that's what I'm asking.

Comment: @DavidRoberts You are right, sorry, I meant "Simplicial objects in algebraic topology", Theorem 26.9 (on page 121)

Comment: @მამუკაჯიბლაძე: How does this help you prove the Hurewicz theorem?

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams Why hide it - it turns out I actually don't know. I thought I knew but it turned out I never did.

Answer (score 17):

I’d argue that it boils down to the generator $S^n\to K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ being an $(n+1)$-equivalence.

**More detail:**  If you take the represented version of homology, it is given by 
$$
H_n(X;\mathbb{Z}) \cong [ S^{n+t} , X\wedge K(\mathbb{Z}, t)]
$$
for $t$ large.  Then the Hurewicz map is the map induced
by the generator $g:S^t \to K(\mathbb{Z}, t)$:
$$
\mathrm{H}:
[ S^{n+t} , X\wedge S^k]
\xrightarrow{(\mathrm{id}_X\wedge g)_*}
[ S^{n+t} , X\wedge K(\mathbb{Z}, t)].
$$
If $X$ is $(n-1)$-connected then since $g$ is 
a $(t+1)$-equivalence, the map $(\mathrm{id}_X\wedge g)_*$
is an isomorphism.

**Even MORE detail:**  It is true that the existence of $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ requires genuine work.  But it does not require the Hurewicz theorem.  In fact, you only need to produce an $(n-1)$-connected space $X$ with $\pi_n(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ (then you can take a Postnikov section to get $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$).  And there is an obvious candidate:  $S^n$.

So the question becomes, how can you show $\pi_n(S^n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$ (the connectivity is easy as a result of $S^n = * \cup D^n$ and the cellular approximation theorem). We can prove it for $n = 1$ using covering spaces, and use Freudenthal to get it for higher $n$ (it's a little tricky for $n= 2$, but luckily $S^1$ is an H-space).

What about proving Freudenthal?  The suspension $\Sigma: \pi_n(X) \to \pi_{n+1}(\Sigma X)$ is equivalent to the map induced by $\sigma: X\to 
\Omega\Sigma X$, adjoint to $\mathrm{id}_{\Sigma X}$, and its connectivity can be estimated using the James construction.

What about the James construction?  This lovely paper

> Fantham, Peter; James, Ioan(4-OX); Mather, Michael
>   On the reduced product construction. (English summary) 
>   Canad. Math. Bull. 39 (1996), no. 4, 385–389.

gives a proof based only on Mather's second cube theorem, which itself depends on some point-set topology due to Str{\o}m (no relation).

Comment: How so? Is it because $S^n$ is a Moore space? That the Eilenberg-Mac Lane space represents on cohomology?

Comment: What is your definition of $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$?  The various usual definitions are not obviously equivalent without the Hurewicz Theorem.  Similarly, many of the standard facts about connectivity of spectra and maps implicitly use the Hurewicz Theorem, so it is far from clear that you have a non-circular argument.

Comment: Without the Hurewicz theorem how do you know $K(\mathbb{Z},n)$ exists?

Comment: @Oscar: I don't know what construction you have in mind that requires the Hurewicz theorem, but all that I think I need to construct $K(\mathbb{Z}, n)$ is a model for the classifying space functor $B$ which takes topological abelian groups to topological abelian groups, which IIRC was written down by Segal, applied $n$ times to $\mathbb{Z}$. Verifying that this space has the correct homotopy groups just requires knowing that $\Omega B G \cong G$. But then I guess verifying that it represents (co)homology requires more.

Comment: More detail on Eilenberg-Mac Lane spaces added.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan why do you need more to see it represents cohomology? Are we not allowed to use the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms? I don't think those use the Hurewicz theorem... you have a spectrum, so it satisfies all the axioms except maybe the dimension one, and, as you say, that follows from looping down till you get to $\mathbb{Z}$. I think with this you forego the need for Freudenthal and such in the "even more" part of the answer.

Comment: @DylanWilson I think you'd want to check your constructions carefully before you claim anything involving spectra is done without some kind of appeal to Freudenthal.

Comment: In this case I used spectrum as a shorthand. What I mean is that we have a sequence of spaces $K_n$ and homotopy equivalences $\Omega K_n \cong K_{n-1}$. The Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms then become the fact that $[-, X]$ takes cofiber sequences to exact sequences, and the suspension axiom is the loops-suspension adjunction. So I think that's all I've used. The only thing I can think of is that maybe it's not obvious that the $K_n$ have no homotopy *below* dimension $n$? But again, if we're allowed cellular approximation, then this is okay from the explicit cell structure on geometric realization

Answer (score 9):

Here is a sketch of the proof, some details filled below. All categories
are $(\infty,1)$-categories and all functors are $(\infty,1)$-functors
unless specified otherwise. The notion of a topological abelian group
can be defined within higher topos theory. The category of abelian
groups is equivalent to the category of cartesian functors from a
certain representing category $\mathrm{\mathcal{T}Ab}$ with finite
products to the topos. The 1-truncation of $\mathrm{\mathcal{T}Ab}$
is equivalent to the Lawvere theory of abelian groups, and its models
in any 1-truncated topos is the classic category of abelian groups.
The important thing here is that the free abelian groups functor is
defined naturally for any cocomplete category with finite products
as a colimit of finite powers of the generating object, thus it is
preserved by any functor which preserves colimits and finite products.
In particular, it it preserved by the $n$-truncation functor $\tau_{\leqslant n}:\mathrm{Space}\to\mathrm{Space}_{\leqslant n}$,
since $\mathrm{Space}$ is a topos (HTT, lemma 6.5.1.2, also [on
nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-truncated+object+of+an+%28infinity%2C1%29-category#GeneralPropsTruncation)). Hurewicz theorem requires working not with $\mathrm{Space}$
itself, but with the category of pointed and, more generally, $k$-connected
spaces $\mathrm{Space}^{>k}$. The truncation functor on these categories
also preserves finite products and colimits. The free abelian group
functor on pointed spaces acts as $\left(X,\ast\right)\mapsto F\left(X\right)/F\left(\ast\right)$,
i.e. as reduced homology. Note that it's just a specialization of
the general definition. $F$ maps the subcategory $\mathrm{Space}^{>k}\hookrightarrow\mathrm{Space}^{>-1}$
to itself, since $\mathrm{Space^{>k}}$ is closed under finite products
and small colimits. This means that for any $\left(n-1\right)$-connected
space $X$ the canonical morphism $X\to FX$ under truncation induces
a morphism $\tau_{\leqslant n}X\to F\tau_{\leqslant n}X$, where $\tau_{\leqslant n}X$
lives in the category of $\left(n-1\right)$-connected $n$-truncated
spaces $\mathrm{Space}_{\leqslant n}^{>n-1}$ and $F$ is the free
abelian group functor for $\mathrm{Space}_{\leqslant n}^{>n-1}$.
The loop–deloop adjunction induces an equivalence between the categories
$\mathrm{Space}^{>k}$ and $E_{k+1}\mathrm{Grp}\left(\mathrm{Space}\right)$
— $E_{k+1}$-monoidal group objects in spaces, thus $\mathrm{Space}_{\leqslant n}^{>n-1}\simeq E_{n}\mathrm{Grp}\left(\mathrm{Set}\right)$.
For $n=0$ $E_{n}\mathrm{Grp}\left(\mathrm{Set}\right)\simeq\mathrm{Set}_{\bullet}$
and the Hurewicz moprhism is the inclusion of a pointed set into its
free abelian group (note that the marked point maps to $0$). For
$n=1$ $E_{n}\mathrm{Grp}\left(\mathrm{Set}\right)\simeq\mathrm{Grp}\left(\mathrm{Set}\right)$,
the abelian groups in the $1$-category of groups are just classical
abelian groups and the Hurewicz morphism is the abelianization of
the group $\pi_{1}\left(X\right)$. For $n>1$ the sequence of $E_{n}$-monoids
stabilizes, all $E_{n}\mathrm{Grp}\left(\mathrm{Set}\right)\simeq\mathrm{Ab}\left(\mathrm{Set}\right)$.
The category of abelian groups in the $1$-category of abelian groups
is the $1$-category of abelian groups itself, thus both the forgetful
functor and the free abelian group functor are identity and the Hurewicz
morphism is the identity as well, QED.

The trickiest part of the theorem is to actually state it: we need
to define the free abelian group functor $F$ as a functor on the
category of spaces (here and below all categories are $(\infty,1)$-categories
and all functors are $(\infty,1)$-functors unless specified otherwise)
and show that it can be constructed via finite products and small
colimits. This isn't obvious since the natural homotopization of abelian
monoids is the category of $E_{\infty}$ monoids, which is the category
of algebras over the operad of abelian groups $\mathrm{Comm}$. Thus
we will proceed in several steps: first introduce the notion of $E_{\infty}$-groups
which are the same as connective spectra. The abelian groups are $H\mathbb{Z}$-modules
in the category of spectra (by Dold–Kan correspondence the category
of simplicial abelian groups is equivalent to the category of non-negative
chain complexes, which are equivalent to connective $H\mathbb{Z}$-module
spectra). Here $H\mathbb{Z}$ is an $E_{\infty}$-ring spectrum which
is the 0-truncation of the sphere spectrum. The free abelian group
functor in the category of spectra is thus $X\mapsto H\mathbb{Z}\otimes X$,
by the universality of left adjoints the free abelian group functor
in the category of spaces is $X\mapsto\Omega^{\infty}(H\mathbb{Z}\otimes\Sigma^{\infty}X_{+})$.
This is the composition of three freeness functors: the free $E_{\infty}$-monoid
one, followed by the group completion of a monoid, followed by the
free $H\mathbb{Z}$-algebra one which is the smash product of spectra.
The first two ones are of the required type (products and colimits)
as free algebra functors. The third one is also of this type since
the smash product aka $E_{\infty}$-tensor product can be represented
by the Day convolution, which involves only finite products and colimits,
of the corresponding functors on the representing Lawvere theory of
$E_{\infty}$-groups. Note that if we model this theory in $1$-categories
rather than $\infty$-categories, then the $E_{\infty}$-monoid structure
reduces to the abelian monoid one, the tensor product is just the
ordinary tensor product over $\mathbb{Z}$ and the whole composition
equals to the free abelian group functor.

Some other trivial applications of the above technique: for any abelian
group $A$ the Hurewicz morphism for $A$-homology on the lowest nontrivial
homotopy group is the composition of abelianization and the map $\pi_{n}\left(X\right)\to A\otimes\pi_{n}\left(X\right)$.
Less trivially, let us consider the free group functor, which is equivalent
to $\Omega\Sigma$. The natural transformation $X\to\Omega\Sigma X$
is described by the Freudenthal's theorem: it is $\left(2n-2\right)$-connected
if $X$ is $\left(n-1\right)$-connected. After looping and truncating
this is equivalent to the statement that on the category of $\left(n-2\right)$-truncated
$E_{n}$-groups the free group functor is an equivalence. This in
turn is equivalent to the statement that the categories of models
of $E_{n+k}$-groups in $n$-categories are equivalent for $k\geqslant1$,
which is a generalization of the claim that $E_{k}\mathrm{Grp}\left(\mathrm{Set}\right)\simeq\mathrm{Ab}$
for $k\geqslant2$ (in fact we don't need the structure of a group,
only a monoid). The structure of $E_{n+k}$-monoid is given by $\left(n+k\right)$
commuting (necessarily equal) associtive multiplications, which amounts
to giving a series of commuting $\left(n+k\right)$-dimensional cubes
which have the muplication maps on edges, the commutativity conditions
on 2-faces etc for all operation arities. The highest degree condition
corresponds to the cube itself and is $\left(n+k\right)$-dimensional.
In an $n$-category it reduces to a relation, i.e. if the corresponding
$\left(n+k\right)$-dimensional paths exists then they are unique
and no relation of higher degree between them is possible, thus any
$E_{n+1}$-monoid is automatically an $E_{n+k}$-monoid.

As usual in category theory, we have moved the burden of work from
the proof of the statement to the definitions, which reduces the actual
proof to some purely formal statements. One could probably say that
it requires a perverted state of mind to claim that the proof above
is "simple", however I still make this claim: it involves
only general facts about higher algebras and higher categories. In
a world where children study homotopy theory instead of set theory
all statements above would be most natural and can be verified mentally.

I think I'll state it concisely: Hurewicz theorem is the statement that for $(n-1)$-connected spaces the $n$-truncation of the morphism into abelianization is an abelianization of $\pi_n$. The truncation commutes with free algebra functor by abstract nonsense and the free algebra is $(n-1)$-connected, thus we study ablianization on the category of $(n-1)$-connected $n$-truncated spaces, which is equivalent to $Set_*$, $Grp$ or $Ab$ depending on $n$, where abelianization is obvious, QED.

Comment: "Here $H\mathbb{Z}$ is an $E_{\infty}$-ring spectrum which is the 0-truncation of the sphere spectrum." Isn't this observation essentially the content of the Hurewicz theorem, as explain by Jeff Strom?

Comment: @OscarRandal-Williams No, because it's a single space of coefficients rather than homology itself. The real content of the proof is how you go from a single space to a colimit of spectra. Jeff Strom's answer relies on Freudenthal's theorem and stabilization, I proceed directly from the definition of free algebras. But of course all approaches will be somewhat related. I rely only on general category theory, thus I believe the proof works in any topos and for any algebraic theory, not only $\mathbb Z$-homology of spaces.

Comment: @Oscar If you mean that I need Hurewicz or Freudenthal to prove that $\pi_0(\mathbb S) = \mathbb Z$, I don't. By the sphere spectrum I mean the universal $E_\infty$-group. It's 0-truncation is a universal abelian group, QED. If you wish, you can define $\mathbb S$ as the group completion of the groupoid of finite sets.

Comment: As someone who likes and uses $\infty$-categories, this answer terrifies me. If I am correctly interpreting your insistence on using only native $\infty$-categorical concepts (which means you aren't allowed to cheat and get the symmetric monoidal structure on $Sp$ using a model structure or anything) you have used all of the following things to prove the *Hurewicz theorem*: the fact that spectra has the structure of symmetric monoidal $\infty$-category, the definition and basic properties of various $\infty$-operads, $\infty$-categorical Day convolution, the fact that algebras over

Comment: (contd) varius $\infty$-operads have nice explicit descriptions in the 1-categorical setting, the fact that grouplike $E_k$-spaces are equivalent to $k$-fold loop spaces (which includes checking somehow that $\Omega^k$ preserves sifted colimits as a functor on connected enough spaces- a fact which seems dangerously close to the Hurewicz theorem already), the claim that the sphere spectrum (and I mean like.. THE sphere spectrum) is the universal $E_{\infty}$-group (including defining what that means), which is roughly the Barrat-Priddy-Quillen theorem, and the ($\infty$-)Dold-Kan correspondence

Comment: I find this absolutely ridiculous.

Comment: @DylanWilson Well, the OP has asked for an abstract nonsense proof. I have delivered on both points, didn't I? More seriously, the essential part of the proof is in the last paragraph. Most of the rest is required for the comparison to classic singular homology. The proof is trivial if you can define homology $\infty$-categorically in a simple way, e.g. if you know some simple description of the abelian operad (I don't). I consider Day convolution and operads to be a trivial matter. You're not terrified by Lawvere theories or coends, are you? (..cont)

Comment: It's not a matter of innate complexity but a matter of historical precedence and inperfect axiomatization that $\infty$-categorical constructions are regarded as something vastly more difficult than classical ones. I also don't need that the universal $E_\infty$-group is THE sphere spectrum or BPQ theorem, it is mentioned only for comparison with other answer. The fact that groups can be delooped is a fundamental property of $\infty$-topoi, there is no getting around that one. Jeff also requires either that or Dold-Kan to construct $K(A, n)$. (...)

Comment: Finally, I describe a general approach to such algebraic questions. It may be an overkill for Hurewicz, but it is more powerful. E.g. I show that it proves Freudenthal, there are probably other interesting algebras which would be amenable to the method.

Answer (score 7):

Here are some thoughts; I don't know if they'll add up to a satisfying answer. Let $X$ be $(n-1)$-connected. We have a Hurewicz map $\pi_n(X) \to H_n(X)$ given by applying $H_n$ to maps $S^n \to X$ and we want to know that it's an isomorphism (or abelianization if $n = 1$). Applying $\text{Hom}(-, A)$ for an arbitrary abelian group $A$, the Yoneda lemma shows that this is equivalent to knowing that the corresponding map

$$\text{Hom}(H_n(X), A) \to \text{Hom}(\pi_n(X), A)$$

is always an isomorphism. Now, by the universal coefficient theorem $\text{Hom}(H_n(X), A)$ can be identified with $H^n(X, A)$, so this map can be thought of as the map

$$H^n(X, A) \to \text{Hom}(\pi_n(X), A)$$

given by applying $\pi_n$ to maps $X \to B^n A$, once we've shown that the classifying space $B^n A \cong K(A, n)$ exists and represents cohomology (I don't know off the top of my head whether there's a clean way to do this that avoids the Hurewicz theorem).

The nice thing about having massaged the statement to this form is that now it is entirely a statement about computing homotopy classes of maps and we can hope for a reasonably conceptual $\infty$-categorical way to understand, if not non-circularly prove, it. My understanding would use the following: there is a functor $\tau_{\le n}$ sending a space to its $n$-truncation, which is left adjoint to the inclusion from $n$-truncated spaces (spaces with vanishing $\pi_k, k \ge n+1$) into spaces, and which correspondingly has the universal property that

$$\text{Map}(\tau_{\le n} X, Y) \cong \text{Map}(X, Y)$$

for any $n$-truncated space $Y$. Now, $B^n A$ is $n$-truncated, so setting $Y = B^n A$ and $X$ as above gives

$$\text{Map}(\tau_{\le n} X, B^n A) \cong \text{Map}(X, B^n A)$$

or, restated in terms of cohomology,

$$H^n(\tau_{\le n} X, A) \cong H^n(X, A).$$

In other words, $H^n$ only depends on the $n$-truncation of $X$. This is useful because the assumption that $X$ is $(n-1)$-connected implies that $\tau_{\le n} X$ has only a single nonzero homotopy group, and hence it can be identified with $B^n \pi_n(X)$. Now we've reduced to showing that

$$\text{Map}(B^n \pi_n(X), B^n A) \cong \text{Hom}(\pi_n(X), A)$$

which at least morally follows from taking loop spaces $n$ times and using that abelian groups fully faithfully embed into $n$-fold loop spaces, $n \ge 1$ (for $n = 1$ and $\pi_1$ nonabelian, the same statement for groups). I also don't know whether there's a clean proof of this that avoids the Hurewicz theorem!

Answer (score 6):

One approach is to replace the free abelian group functor with the free commutative monoid functor, also known as the infinite symmetric product.

Let $X$ be a pointed CW complex, and let $\mbox{SP}^\infty(X)$ be the infinite symmetric product. By Dold-Thom theorem, if $X$ is connected then the homotopy groups of $\mbox{SP}^\infty(X)$ are the homology groups of $X$.

The advantage of $\mbox{SP}^\infty$ over the free abelian group functor is that it has a natural filtration, and a cell structure that can be analyzed. Given Dold-Thom theorem, the Huriewicz theorem is equivalent to saying that if $X$ is $k-1$-connected, then the map $X\to \mbox{SP}^\infty(X)$ is $k+1$ connected (for simplicity let's assume $k>1$). This can be proved by analysing the cell structure on $\mbox{SP}^\infty(X)$. You can find this  in chapter 6 of the book of Aguilar, Gitler and Prieto.